# How can I connect to a MonoTouch Mac build server from two computers?

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have two Windows PCs, but we have only one Mac to build iOS applications. We don't want to build simultaneously, just want to connect to the same mac. I managed to start two instances of build server on the mac which listens to 5000, 5001 ports, but I can't find a way to change the default 5000 port in the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

As per Apple's licensing restrictions, you need one Mac per developer, so 2 developers cannot build simultaneously on one Mac (these restrictions are reinforced by Visual Studio). That being said, you should easily be able to connect one at a time to the Mac build server.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to build simultaneously, I just want to connect to the same mac from 2 Visual Studio, and build separately.